# Add new column into df

Tags: dataframe, datatable

For A it would look like this.

```
Name    Date       Value     NewColumn   other columns
A       2000-01      0.5      
A       2001-03      0.4      0
A       2002-02      1.0      1  
A       2003-05      0.9      0
A       2004-06      0.9
A       2006-03      0.4        <- no previous year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
Name      Date       Value
A       2000-01      0.5
A       2001-03      0.4 
A       2002-02      1.0
A       2003-05      0.9
A       2004-06      0.9
A       2006-03      0.4 
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%                                # for each name
  mutate(change = Value/lag(Value)-1,               # get the change in value (increase or decrease)
         year = as.numeric(substr(Date, 1, 4)),     # get the year from the date
         NewColumn = case_when(change > 0.01 & lag(year) == year-1 ~ 1,         # if change is more than 1% and the previous row is 1 year before flag as 1
                               change < -0.01 & lag(year) == year-1 ~ 0)) %>%   # if change is less than 1% and the previous row is 1 year before flag as 0
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Name  Date    Value  change  year NewColumn
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 A     2000-01   0.5  NA      2000        NA
# 2 A     2001-03   0.4  -0.200  2001         0
# 3 A     2002-02   1     1.5    2002         1
# 4 A     2003-05   0.9  -0.100  2003         0
# 5 A     2004-06   0.9   0      2004        NA
# 6 A     2006-03   0.4  -0.556  2006        NA
```

You can remove some unnecessary variables. I left them just to help you understand how the process works.

Comment: Your result is not in line with OP's expectations because you used the wrong threshold of 0.1 (10%) instead of 0.01 (1%).

Answer (score 1):

As the question has been tagged with `data.table`, here is a corresponding solution which uses some tricky arithmetic with `NA` and logical values:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[order(Date), NewColumn := {
  yr <- year(lubridate::ymd(Date, truncated = 1L))
  chg <- Value / shift(Value) - 1.0
  NA^(yr - shift(yr) != 1L) * NA^(!abs(chg) > 0.01) * (sign(chg) / 2.0 + 0.5)
}, by = Name][]
```

> ```
>    Name    Date Value NewColumn
> 1:    A 2000-01   0.5        NA
> 2:    A 2001-03   0.4         0
> 3:    A 2002-02   1.0         1
> 4:    A 2003-05   0.9         0
> 5:    A 2004-06   0.9        NA
> 6:    A 2006-03   0.4        NA
> ```

The trick here is to use the fact that `NA^0` is 1 and `NA^1` is `NA`, and that `FALSE` corresponds to 0 and `TRUE` to 1, so that

```
NA^c(FALSE, TRUE)
```

returns

> ```
> [1]  1 NA
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Name      Date       Value
A       2000-01      0.5
A       2001-03      0.4 
A       2002-02      1.0
A       2003-05      0.9
A       2004-06      0.9
A       2006-03      0.4 ")
```